# LINQ to Entities - Many-To-Many queries with code-first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Let's say i have this:

```
    public partial class AccessMask
{
    public int AccessMaskID { get; set; }
=== bla bla bla ===

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Role { get; set; }
}

    public partial class Role
{

    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    === bla bla bla==

    public virtual ICollection<Forum> Forum { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rank> Rank { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccessMask> AccessMask { get; set; }
}
```

And now a big question. How to make query between those two? As you may see it's many-to-many relation. And What I want to do is to join this and get access mask connected with role.
bla bla bla- some random properties that are completly irrevelant.

UPDATE!

I know I can use: 
    Include()
But using it for lot's of queries.. will be a bad idea. Because I have quite a few many-to-many relationships that look similiar.
Or Do I have to simply redeisgn my model, to something more traditional with joining entity ?

Comment: tip: simplify your code and take out properties not relevant to the m-m question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For retrieving data, it will work the same way as any other navigation property:

```
Role myRole = context.Where(x=>x.Id=123).FirstOrDefault();
ICollection<AccessMask> masks = myRole.AccessMask;
```

However, I have had a very rough time of getting many-to-many data to save.